# Is there a way to send push notifications with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, push-notification

Hello I wonder is there a way to send push notifications with Django to a user.

I have a website that accepts/refuses vacation demands.

When a user sends a vacation demand my Django app sends email to the CEO to notify him that there was a new vacation request.

When the CEO accepts the demand it sends email to the user that the demand was accepted.

But since the CEO receives plenty of emails a day and he barely sees my emails i would like to make a browser notification whenever he opens the browser to see notification from my website that a demand is waiting to be approved/refused.

Is there a library that can do that for me,

I've tried [django-webpush](https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush) but I couldn't managed it to work even though I
followed all the steps.

Comment: Not something I've done but just an idea you could create a method in your backend and send a request to it all n load to check for emails. Maybe have that request send every 60 seconds whilst the browser is open?

Comment: I want it to send the notification even if the website is not open in a tab like facebook when you open your browser like chrome sends the notifications @TPHughes

Comment: Typically you can use Django Channels for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i checked them out but I don't understand how they work at all i have searched the whole internet but if you have some source to share would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, since your have the information that your user accessed your server at least once. checkout this lib

https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications

**EDIT** Gonna put more information about it

If you expect receive one response from your backend to your backend you can write some watcher to receive new data, or create one plugin, or use sockets or even make your frontend send one call to backend with some interval time to check if there is any new messages...

Lets split up a bit

**1 - Watcher**

Using watchers you can just watch your backend to any changes... build it from scratch i thing i a bit "hard", you can use some modern frontend framework that already have it like Angular, React, Vue... and capture new incomes messages from your backend and create Notification instance in your browser and your it to your user (i guess they will have to keep the page openned to do it... im not 100% sure)

**2 - Plugins**

You can build one plugin to add to your browser and receive the data from your server... since you already in browser is more easier to use browser functions

**3 - Sockets**

The common way to make 2 ways comunication from frontend to backend, most used with chats and things arround that, just create one channel of communications between this 2 sides and you will be able to send and receive messages from frontend or backend

**4 - Dirty Way**

If you not get the time to implement it like supposed to do with quality you can go the dirty way, just setup one ajax in your page to check your backend to new messages every 5 minutes? or more or less... and if find any new data (*of course you will have to handle it on your backend like any other suggestions above*) and then you create one new notification in your browser and show to your user...

**Im sure there is bunch of libs that already do most of things to you, so just search a bit and test until you find anything that fits your need**

Comment: not yet, but in logic is simple... how control the interface is Javascript. so you can setup to show the notifications with it, the only thing you need is a socket or configure ajax calls to your backend to receive updated data... the only problem is your frontend expect new data from backend... since only modern JS frameworks do that... the regular path is frontend call the backend no the other way

Comment: Socket looks the easier way to do that... thinks about a webchat... you in client side receive messages from someone at backend... so instead of receive message you will receive data that will trigger your Notification class at frontend

Comment: I do have some pure javascript project on my github to show notifications, let me grab it

Comment: https://github.com/Diegow3b/Browser-Notification-ES6   Just throw your received data and be happy

Comment: If you will use sockets, you can use Tornado or socketIo... has been a long time since i saw one project with socketio... Tornado is more common used 
http://django-tornado-websockets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Okay well I did something so IDEA... i have a service-worker registered (but i don't know how to structure it) it will keep a cookie or something to identify the user that so the service worker can send me  then onBrowser open will send information to the server to pick all of his notifications and display them to him

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174954/discussion-between-kostadin-slavov-and-diego-vinicius).